# How do I publish ASP.net MVC application to existing Azure virtual machine from VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops

I am looking to automate the build and deployment for our web applications in Azure.

The Web applications are hosted on IIS in a virtual machine (classic). I have web deploy installed/enabled on it. We have been using TeamCity to deploy these apps using web deploy, but we have chosen to go with Visual studio team services, hence intend to use the release management feature.

I already have configured the building and packaging step using a publishing profile. The output is the web deploy package.

Now I am stuck at the stage where I install that package on to the virtual machine. I can't find a task which will let me do that.

[image: Azure Release Management - Add task]

Do I have to use to powershell script to deploy using webdeploy?

I found these references, but I have no idea how to use them:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/vs-azure-tools-publish-webapplicationvm.md

https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/vs-azure-tools-publishing-using-powershell-scripts.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider the Azure VM IIS as a normal IIS server and there are several ways to deploy web deploy package to IIS server. Refer to "Installing the package" section in this link for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx

The easiest way I think is installing "Web Deploy Remote Agent Service" (Installed when install web deploy completely) on the Azure VM and then add a task in "Release" to run the "xxx.deploy.cmd" file in the web deploy package like following format:

```
xxx.deploy.cmd /Y /M:AzureVMName.cloudapp.net /U:username /P:password
```

Comment: Yup.. that's what I ended up doing .. forgot to update this. 

Thanks!!